# Intermediate data processing for consecutive networks and backwarding

Tags: python, pytorch

I have encountered a tricky problem using PyTorch.

I have two networks n1 and n2 to be trained. The structure of my model is something like

```
def Model():
    def forward(self):
        output1 = net1(input1) # feed forward of network 1
        input2 = function() # preparing input for network 2 containing iterations, which depends on output1
        output2 = net2(input2) # feed forward of network 2

    def function(self):
        # iteration using self.output1
        # takes relatively long to run (a few minutes)

    def backward(self):
        self.loss = loss1 + loss2  # losses based on output1 and output2
        self.loss.backward()
```

The net1 was pre-trained for a few epoches to ensure meaningful output, and everything was correct and running well. Then net2 was added, and two networks are supposed to be trained simultaneously. The observation is that loss.backward() takes too long (around 20 minutes). I assume it has something to do with the function() in the forward() method, because when I changed the iteration to a smaller size, the backwarding was much faster. However, for the complete model, I cannot decrease the iteration size.

So my question is, does the loss.backward() method somehow “re-runs” the function() method in forward()? If it is true, any suggestions to avoid this problem, e.g. changing the structure of my Model?

Many thanks for any help!

Update: the function() is something like

```
# idx contains the indexes of some pre-defined locations
for b in range(batch_size):
    for i in range(150):
        for j in range(i, 150):
            idx_i, idx_j = idx[i], idx[j]
            input2[b, idx_i, idx_j] = some_criterion(output1[b, idx_i-2:idx_i+3, idx_j-2:idx_j+3])  # that is why I need to use iteration, because the output depends on the neighbours
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding of how 'backward(self)' works. What your code above accomplishes is that your backward-function recursively calls itself.
Simply call loss.backward() whenever you calculate the losses in your training code, no need to define 'backward()' for your model.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I re-named the method backward() to calculate_loss(), and it is still the same. Do you have possibly any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, it is rather difficult to help optimize a function whose contents are hidden. It would probably help if you showed what was in 'function()'. My wildest guess is that function() uses the CPU instead of GPU.

Comment: I updated the question, please have a look :) I think you are right, inside the function(), the iteration is using CPU. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: The nested for-loops explains  why the code is slow. As a first step, try list comprehension:

`input2 = [[[some_criterion(output1[b, idx_i-2:idx_i+3, idx_j-2:idx_j+3]) for b in range(batch_size)] for j in range(i, 150)] for i in range(150)]`. Otherwise, you'll have to try rewriting your triple-loops into numpy operations, which might be a bit complicated.